Slow Data Loading and Low GPU Utilization in PyTorch Federated Learning with Frequent Client Switching
I'm working on a federated learning project using PyTorch, focusing on medical imaging (MRI) data. Despite using an SSD, the dataset loading phase is unusually slow, and the GPU utilization remains very low across global epochs. Each client handles a significant volume of data, and the frequent client switching seems to exacerbate the issue. I'm looking for ways to optimize data loading and enhance GPU utilization.
Data Details:
Each .npy file corresponds to a pre-processed three-dimensional MRI, approximately 20MB in size.
Each client manages between 500 and 1000 such files, contributing to a total dataset size of around 100GB distributed across clients.
Here's a breakdown of my current setup:
I have a custom dataset class, TrainCNN_Data, which reads .npy files. Each client in the federated learning framework initializes this dataset and loads it using a DataLoader during training. On the server side, training involves iterating through selected clients and training them one by one.
Server-Side Code for Client Training:
class Server:
    def __init__(self, clients, global_rounds):
        self.clients = clients
        self.global_rounds = global_rounds

    def train_clients(self):
        for i in range(self.global_rounds + 1):
            self.selected_clients = self.select_clients()
            for client in self.selected_clients:
                client.train(i)

Client-Side Data Loading and Training Code:
class Client:
    def prepare_dataset(self, seed):
        self.train_data = TrainCNN_Data(0, self._dataset_dir, _csv_dir_train, seed=seed, classification=classification)

    def load_train_data(self, batch_size=None):
        if batch_size is None:
            batch_size = self.batch_size
        train_dataloader = DataLoader(self.train_data,
                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                      num_workers=self.num_workers,
                                      pin_memory=self.pin_memory,
                                      drop_last=True)
        return train_dataloader

    def train(self, epoch):
        all_trainloader = self.load_train_data()
        for i, data in enumerate(all_trainloader):
            x, y = data
            x = x.to(self.device)
            # training code...

Code for the TrainCNN_Data class:
class TrainCNN_Data(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, split_method, data_source, csv_train_dir, seed=666, classification=None):
        if classification is None:
            classification = ['NL', 'AD']
        random.seed(seed)
        self.split_method = split_method
        self.data_source = data_source
        self.csv_train_dir = csv_train_dir

        if self.split_method == 0:
            self.Data_list, self.Label_list = read_labels_from_csv(csv_train_dir, classification=classification)
        else:
            self.Data_list, self.Label_list, self.origin_datasets = read_labels_and_origin_from_csv(csv_train_dir, classification=classification)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.Data_list)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, slice):
            return [self.get_single_item(i) for i in range(*idx.indices(len(self.Data_list)))]
        else:
            return self.get_single_item(idx)

    def get_single_item(self, idx):
        label = self.Label_list[idx]
        if self.split_method == 0:
            data = np.load(os.path.join(self.data_source, self.Data_list[idx] + '.npy')).astype(np.float32)
        else:
            data = np.load(os.path.join(self.data_source[self.origin_datasets[idx]], self.Data_list[idx] + '.npy')).astype(np.float32)
        data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=0)
        return data, label

To analyze performance bottlenecks,
I set up 2 clients, each allocated 100 .npy files.
I used the torch.profile tool to observe the time taken for one iteration of training on one of the  2 nodes.
I noticed that 78% of the time was spent loading the dataset.
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
                                                   Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg    # of Calls                                                                      Input Shapes  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
enumerate(DataLoader)#_MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter...        78.45%       40.452s        78.45%       40.453s     919.382ms            44                                                                                []  
                                        cudaMemcpyAsync        20.50%       10.569s        20.50%       10.569s      33.028ms           320                                                                                []  
                                               aten::to         0.00%       1.961ms        14.79%        7.625s     190.635ms            40                               [[8, 1, 181, 217, 181], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]  
                                         aten::_to_copy         0.00%       1.387ms        14.78%        7.623s     190.586ms            40                                   [[8, 1, 181, 217, 181], [], [], [], [], [], []]  
                                            aten::copy_         0.00%       1.802ms        14.78%        7.621s     190.527ms            40                                [[8, 1, 181, 217, 181], [8, 1, 181, 217, 181], []]  
                                               aten::to         0.00%     473.806us         5.73%        2.957s      24.641ms           120                                                  [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]  
                                         aten::_to_copy         0.00%       1.651ms         5.73%        2.957s      32.493ms            91                                                      [[], [], [], [], [], [], []]  
                                            aten::copy_         0.00%       1.983ms         5.73%        2.954s      32.467ms            91                                                                      [[], [], []]  
                                       cudaLaunchKernel         0.24%     122.497ms         0.24%     122.497ms       8.800us         13920                                                                                []  
                    Optimizer.step#CosineOptimizer.step         0.06%      32.896ms         0.18%      90.326ms       2.258ms            40                                                                                []  
-------------------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Self CPU time total: 51.566s

Questions:

Are there any common pitfalls or inefficiencies in the way I'm handling data loading across multiple clients that could be causing these issues?
How can I optimize the data loading process in this federated learning context to improve both training speed and GPU usage?

Any insights or suggestions on how to tackle these challenges would be greatly appreciated!

@nneonneo  I'm new to Stack Overflow and don't know how to respond to feedback. Thank you for your professional advice!
